# C programs that refer directly to a numeric address, these processes physically refer to same place?

Tags: c, memory

Let's say we have compiled a C program that refer directly to a numeric address , and then executed two. So these two processes physically refer to the same place? If not, how can you refer to different physical spaces?

Comment: Most modern non-embedded systems (Linux, Windows, macOS, BSD, ...) use virtual memory mapping.

Comment: Most embedded RTOS don't. Worth a mention. E.g.: VxWorks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on the actual platform. On many embedded systems this might be the case, but for example on x86 in protected mode each application gets its own address space and the [virtual memory manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) translates virtual addresses of each application into physical memory addresses. This way applications end up being isolated from each other and can have their code running at exactly the same address.

When processes (or modules) must share the same address space, a common technique is to work with *relocatable binaries*, also known as [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). That is achieved by creating a fixup table at link time and "fixing up" the loaded binary right after loading.

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the hardware.

On systems with virtual memory management a process is running in its own "sandbox" with the entire memory space available to it. Multiple processes may access the same address, but virtual memory manager would give each one a separate page in physical address space, so the two processes would not "collide" over the same item in memory.

On systems without virtual memory management there is no protection: if two processes refer to the same address, they would be accessing the same location in memory.

**Note:** Accessing an address that has not been allocated to your program is undefined behavior. For this reason, programs that access a hardcoded addresses may be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't. At least not in modern operating systems.

Every process has its own virtual memory space. It has nothing to do with the actual address in the physical DRAM.

In short, it means that every process theoretically has 4GB of memory (in 32 bit architecture), but most of it isn't even mapped to actual physical memory. And if it does, it usually won't point to the same physical address in a different process.

But it can be done. Two processes can share memory! If you will generously ask the OS to map the same memory for both of the processes. This is called mapped memory. Look it up.